# Search two dates and populate DataGridView with dates in between from xml file

Tags: c#, xml, winforms, datagridview, xml-serialization

I am using xml serializer, I want to create a form which allows the user to select a date and then pick a second date and the system will populate the DataGridView with all the event dates in between the two dates. I've looked at tutorials online but they all use sql and not xml.

The perfect scenario should be a user picks date1 and then picks date2, the system retrieves the dates from xmlfile1 which are in between date1 to date2 and populates the information on the DataGridView

can you please give a code for example as well.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?> - <eventdetails> - </eventdetails>
```

includes, event, location and date-time as nodes.

Comment: Replace the sql parts of the tutorials with your Xml Get operation. In the end you should still be assigning DataGrid.Datasource = some collection, just make it from your XDocument or however you are Getting your data.

Comment: I think you need provide the specific xml file first. Then, we can give some help to you.